# Android HTTP Get to api

Tags: java, android, http, get

I´m trying to get data from my api. In postman the request works, here´s the response:

```
 {
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconID": 14,
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconDescription": "b2",
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconLat": 12.3123,
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconLon": 32.123,
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconImgX": 45,
    "ips_Beacons_BeaconImgY": 123
}
```

I´ve tried and i got the response with Okhttp. However it stopped working for some reason.

Although i got the response, i wish to serialize the json string it and instanciate objects. But i couldn´t get the response out of the onSuccess method inside the callback.
This is what i had that workd but doens´t work anymore:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
   String url ="http://192.168.1.95:44374/api/beacons";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                String myResponse = response.body().string();
                listBeacons = objectMapper.readValue(myResponse, new TypeReference<List<Beacon>>(){});
                Log.i(TAG, myResponse);
            }
        }
    });
```

I need the listBeacons List to perform other operations outside this activity.